# Stop or destroy a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, destroy

I have a push menu and it has an animated gradient but I only want it to animated/play when the menu is open, obviously for performance reasons.

My gradient plugin code is as follows:

```
// Animated Gradient
var colors = new Array(
   [62,35,255],
   [60,255,60],
   [255,35,98],
   [45,175,230],
   [255,0,255],
   [255,128,0]);

var step = 0;
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

var gradientSpeed = 0.001;

function updateGradient()
{

if ( $===undefined ) return;

  var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
  var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
  var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
  var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

  var istep = 1 - step;
  var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
  var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
  var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
  var color1 = "rgb("+r1+","+g1+","+b1+")";

  var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
  var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
  var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
  var color2 = "rgb("+r2+","+g2+","+b2+")";

  $('#primary-menu').css({
    background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
    background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});

step += gradientSpeed;
if ( step >= 1 )
{
    step %= 1;
    colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
    colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];

    colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;

}
}
```

I have managed to only play the animated gradient when I open the menu but I'm having trouble stopping it when I close the menu, **how can I do this?**:

```
showmenu.onclick = function() {

    if ($('nav').hasClass('visible')) {

        // Opened menu code here 

    } else {

        // Closed menu code here

        // Initialise plugin when menu is open
        setInterval(updateGradient,10);

    }

};
```

Comment: The plugin initialization is in the close code part. Is that normal?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Do not fear, that was my mistake! Updated the code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You need to clearInterval()

Instead of just calling `setInterval()` assign it to a variable. Both `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` return an identifier so they can be stopped at a later time

```
// in scope available to all your handler code
var timer;

// in initialization    
timer = setInterval(updateGradient,10); 

// in handler where you want to stop it    
clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: I see what you're saying and it makes sense but the code above doesn't seem work.

Comment: Likely not putting things in the right places. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co or other code share site

Comment: I couldn't get the gradient working at all with jsFiddle sorry but I have pasted the new code with your additions here: http://pastebin.com/Lchu9ARJ I appreciate your time...

Comment: Why do you need CSS? Its a jQuery question. I don't see how adding a simple unordered list with dummy links in it will help answer my jQuery problem??

Comment: Not us that needs help keep in mind...and we only do this voluntarily to help out. If I have to cobble together enough html and css myself to match your classes in js and figure out what gets hidden...then I just move on to the next question. Looking at code is one thing...being able to test it in browser and use dev tools on live code is another

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
if ( $('nav').is(':visible') ) { ... }
```